# RegEx для захвата содержимого перед первой '{' и последней '}'

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Вот понадобился RegEx для захвата всего содержимого между (но не включая сами "{" и "}") первой "{" и последней "}", то есть в тексте могут ещё встречаться пары "{}", RegEx нужен под JS, можно ли как то сделать это, просто между "{" и "}" нашёл как сделать, но но чтобы между крайними "{" и "}" непонимаю как.

Comment: `/\{([\s\S]*)\}/` из первой группы забираете результат.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях JavaScript нет возможности указать модификатор `s` (*DOTALL*), поэтому для захвата любого символа здесь можно использовать `[^]`, *любой символ, отличный от пустой строки*.

Так как в остальных языках этот шаблон вызывает ошибку, принято использовать кросс-платформенные эквиваленты: `[^]` = `[\s\S]` = `[\d\D]` = `[\w\W]`. Прчем чаще всего используется `[\s\S]`.

Для захвата текста от первой `{` до *последней* `}` необходим *жадный* квантификатор *, ноль и более повторений.

```js
var s = "Текст до скобки {\nСтрока 1: {123},{456}\nСтрока 2: {Ещё текст: {...}}\r\n}";
console.log(s); // Как выглядит строка
var m = s.match(/{([^]*)}/);
if (m) {                         // Было ли найдено совпадение?
  console.log("'", m[1], "'");   // Если да, получить значение первой группы
}
```

Однако проще в таком случае воспользоваться строковыми методами (код без обработки ошибок):

```js
var s = "Текст до скобки {\nСтрока 1: {123},{456}\nСтрока 2: {Ещё текст: {...}}\r\n}";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("{")+1,s.lastIndexOf("}"));
console.log(s);
```

Comment: И ещё для некоторых `[\s\S\n]`...

Comment: Скорее `[\s\S\r]` - в Visual Studio. В Vim вообще свои заморочки.

Comment: Да, я именно про VS.

Comment: Побольше бы таких развёрнутых ответов, а то RegEx не моя сильная сторона, ибо нужен редко ,и к тому времени когда он нужен снова, уже забываешь что успел изучить в прошлый раз, да ещё отличия JS/pcre постоянно путает.

Comment: Регулярные выражения на JS сильно отличаются от PCRE. Ладно модификаторы (в JS их всего три), необязательные захватывающие группы в JS, не нашедшие совпадения, всегда отличны от null в отличие от PCRE, обратные ссылки с последующей цифрой в строках замены  на JS можно определить как, например, `$10` (=`$1` + `0`), тогда как в  PCRE - `${1}0`. А про обработку совпадений нулевой длины вообще молчу, тут JS вообще не справляется сам, часто нужно и шаблон поправить, и код добавить.